# How to data bind a default value for a user input of type text with knockout.js and override it if user inputs a value

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a form with a user input field which takes numerical values. I want its value set to the value of an another observable if its value is zero when it initially renders.

```
<p>Planned Qunatity: <span id="plQuantity" data-bind="text: plannedQuantity"  /></p>
<p>Issued Quantity: <input id="isQuantity" data-bind="value: issuedQuantity"  /></p>
```

Here I want Issued Quantity to be set to Planned Quantity and also be displayed as its value on the UI if Issued Quantity is zero when it renders.

However, If a user enters a value in that Issued Quantity field, this should override the default value which was set to Planned Quantity initially because Issue Quantity was zero.

I have created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/v0qnp7v2/2/

Comment: Your fiddle contains code quite different from what you show here, and includes some view model code as well. Could you update the question and (a) include a full [mcve] and (b) *all* requirements you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "subscribe" to track changed to your observables. Here is your fiddle modified:

```
self.issuedQuantity.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if (newValue == 0) {
            self.issuedQuantity(self.plannedQuantity());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xr5yLLpa/5/

When you set the value of issuedQuantity to 0 the change is intercepted in the subscribe and set to the value of plannedQuantity. Please note that the change will happen once you exit the textbox - focus is not on the textbox anymore.